# Imacros Clear Cookies For Only Current Page

Tags: javascript, cookies, imacros

I was trying to `clear` cookies only for current page where the imacros script works. Have been googled for a while and found no suitable solution.
Have tried these function

```
document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

inside the `URL GOTO=javascript:(function(){...});`

and also in some other site we need to pass the domain also. So I pass `{{!URLCURRENT}}` as parameter and still nothing happen.

Any solution? Or perhaps I am missing a thing?

**EDIT:**

In case you're wondering complete code, here's it:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:void((function(){var<SP>a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split(";<SP>");for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b="."+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:\.|[^\.]+)/,"")){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,"")){document.cookie=(a[e]+";<SP>domain="+b+";<SP>path="+c+";<SP>expires="+new<SP>Date((new<SP>Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())
```

If I put `alert("Expired<SP>"+f+"<SP>cookies");` It will actually return

```
RuntimeError: unhandled alert dialog detected. Dialog message: "Expired 10 cookies", line 1 (Error code: -1450)
```

Means it ***do*** reads the cookies, but not delete it. Not sure why.

My objectives is to delete user account - so needs to login again if refreshed - for a membership site, but only that site (where the script works).

Answer (score 0):

I just simplified your code. That seems to work. Try to play it.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:void(function(){var<SP>a,e;a=document.cookie.split(";<SP>");for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++)document.cookie=a[e]+";<SP>expires="+(new<SP>Date(0)).toUTCString();}())
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Your script does nothing but timeout, @Shugar

Comment: Hi. I encountered with weird behaviour of this code too. So one should look for another solution.